# Electric Fields of infinite lines compared to infinite sheet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electricity, electrons, gauss-law

[image]

Im not asking for the answer to this question, I just don't understanding what the questions asking.

Im currently covering Gauss's Law in class. We have been discussing how a static electric field is related to the flux through an imaginary object. Whats the question above referring when it says "E falls off"?

Thanks for helping me understand electric fields and Gauss's law!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whats the question above referring when it says "E falls off"?

It simply means the electric field strength dies off as a function of the distance between the charge distribution (source point) and the point (field point) under consideration. From Coulomb's law, it is clear that the electric field due to a point charge $q$ is given by:

$$\vec{E}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r^2}\hat{r}\implies E\propto\frac{1}{r^2}$$

This means, as the separation distance between the field point and the source point increases, the electric field decreases as square of the separation distance. This is what meant by $E$ falls off as $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{r^2}}$.

For a charged sphere with volume charge density $\rho$ and radius $R$, the electric field due to the sphere at some point $r>R$ is given by

$$E=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}\int_V\rho d\tau'=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q_{enc}}{r^2}$$

Here, it is clear that the field falls off with $r^{-2}$.

For a line charge $\lambda$, the field at some point distant $r$ from the line (infinite length) such that the length of the line $l>>r$ is given by

$$E=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{2\lambda}{r}$$

which means, here the electric field falls off with $r^{-1}$.

Now, for an infinite sheet of surface charge density $\sigma$, the electric field at some point distant $r$ from the sheet is given by

$$E=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_o}$$

which is clearly independent of the separation distance $r$.

Answer (score 1):

"$E$ falls off with $\frac{1}{r^2}$" just means that $E(r)\propto\frac{1}{r^2}$, so that when $r$ is increasing, the electric field $E(r)$ falls off much quickly than it does as $\frac{1}{r}$ in the case of infinite line charge.

Answer (score 0):

The formulas are different because $1/r^2$ is valid for **point charge**! 
If you have a collection of point charges "organized in a line" you have to add up all individual electric fields. It is an integration procedure (see the textbook). The result of such integration come up as $1/r.$

Similarly when infinite number of point charges are "organized in a plane" you have to add up all individual fields due to point charges. Following integration procedure you will discover that the field does not depend on $r$ at all...